# Using generics with Morphia & MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, morphia

**Short Description:**

I'm having trouble with reading a document from mongo DB into a java class with a generic property. The error says `java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject`

**Long Description:**

I have a java class / mongoDb-Collection called `RandomDataCollection` which has properties of type `MyGenericProperty<T>`

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @Entity("randomDataCollection")
public class RandomDataCollection {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private MyGenericProperty<Float> temperatureMumbai;

}
```

`MyGenericProperty<T>` looks like this

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class MyGenericProperty<T> {

    private T value;

    private String unit;

}
```

Writing to the DB works as expected...

```
MyGenericProperty<Float> temperatureMumbai = new MyGenericProperty<Float>();
temperatureMumbai.setValue(32.8f);
temperatureMumbai.setUnit("°C");

RandomDataCollection randomData = new RandomDataCollection();
randomData.setName("RandomData0711");
randomData.setTemperatureMumbai(temperatureMumbai);

Datastore datastore = getDatastore();
datastore.save(randomData);
```

...but when I try to read from the DB...

```
randomData = datastore.find(RandomDataCollection.class).filter("name =", "RandomData0711").get();
```

...I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
```

I did find some discussions about generics and morphia but to be honest I didn't know how to apply those to my issue.

I'm running Morphia 1.5.8

Answer (score 1):

There is almost certainly a better way to do this but this worked for me.

```
DBCursor cursor = datastore.find(RandomDataCollection.class).filter("name =", name).fetch().getCursor();
List<RandomDataCollection> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
    RandomDataCollection rec = new RandomDataCollection();
    rec.setId((ObjectId)theObj.get("_id"));
    MyGenericProperty<Float> temperatureMumbai = new MyGenericProperty<Float>();
    BasicDBObject x = (BasicDBObject)theObj.get("temperatureMumbai");
    temperatureMumbai.setValue(x.getFloat("value"));
    temperatureMumbai.setUnit(x.getString("unit"));
    rec.setTemperatureMumbai(temperatureMumbai);
    list.add(rec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm currently using a similar solution - however that way I have to duplicate the code for each type :(